# Proof of Wilson's Theorem using Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Wilson's theorem states that a natural number $n>1$ is a prime number if and only if

$$
(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod {n}
$$

Can we prove it using Fermat's Little theorem? If yes, then how?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Prime_modulus_.E2.80.93_another_proof

Comment: Proving that if $n\gt 1$ and $(n-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{n}$ then $n$ is prime will not involve Fermat's Theorem, but that is the easy direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Consider $(x-1)(x-2)...(x-(p-1))$.